Wordpress дополнительное обновление публикаций после импорта WP All Import Pro
Столкнулся с проблемой обновления записей после импорта WP All Import Pro.
В общем, когда делаю импорт записи сохраняются, все ок.
У меня есть поля созданные через CMB2.
В одном из этих полей я передаю сериализованный массив данных для Google Map, чтобы отображать на странице этой записи локацию на карте.
Если зайти в страницу записи после импорта, то карты этой не видно. Но если зайти в редактирование записи и нажать обновить, то карта появляется.
Подскажите куда копать?

В саппорт WP All Import.
